# Atribuir item selecionado em um <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$("#cep").on('mouseout', function() {

    var url = "http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php";
    var cep = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'cep': cep, 'formato': 'json'},
        async: false,
        url: url,
        success: function(response) {

            if (response.resultado === '1') {

                $("#bairro").val(response.bairro);
                $("#endereco").val(response.logradouro);

                var uf = response.uf;
                $("select#estado option").each(function() {
                    this.selected = (this.text === uf);
                });

                $("#estado").trigger("change");

                var cidade = response.cidade;

                $("select#cidade option").each(function() {
                    this.selected = (this.text === cidade);
                    console.log(this.selected);
                });

            }

        }
    });

});
```

Nessa parte do código deveria "setar" a cidade no combo que foi retornada via ajax. Note que essa parte vem após o `$("#estado").trigger("change")`;

```
var cidade = response.cidade;

$("select#cidade option").each(function() {
   this.selected = (this.text === cidade);
});
```

Não funciona, as cidades são preenchidas, a cidade vem normalmente mas não é "setada" como default no combo box.

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Pode postar aqui o `console.log(response)`? parece-me que ele está a retornar xml.

Comment: Seus options não têm value?

Comment: sim, tem value mas o retorno vem como texto e por isso tenho que usar assim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez funcione colocando o código para executar dentro de um *callback* (*event handler*):

```
        $("select#cidade").one("atualizado", function(){
            var cidade = response.cidade;
            $("select#cidade option").each(function() {
                this.selected = (this.text === cidade);
                console.log(this.selected);
            });
        });

        $("#estado").trigger("change");
```

Estou supondo que existe um *callback* para o evento *change* de *#estado*, para modificar a lista de cidades. Portanto, o código que marca a opção selecionada deve ser executado **depois** da atualização da lista de cidades.

Na sugestão acima, usamos a [função **one** do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/one/) para que um novo  *callback* seja executado **uma única vez**, e em seguida seja descartado.

Você vai precisar também disparar o evento "*atualizado*". Faça isso no teu código. Coloque o comando abaixo imediatamente **após a atualização das `options`** do `select` que contém a lista de cidades do estado:

```
$("select#cidade").trigger("atualizado");
```

Comment: Mesmo dessa forma não consegui sucesso, estou procurando e se encontrar posto aqui para nós

Comment: Provavelmente o outro callback tem uma chamada ajax para carregar as cidades... o código que verifica o selected deveria ser executado após o callback daquele ajax. Se quiser mais ajuda, precisa editar sua pergunta e colocar mais código aí.

Comment: Pronto - atualizei a resposta. Veja se ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado, o código acima funcionou certinho. Fica então a dica para quem precisar.

Comment: Por gentileza, aceite a minha resposta clicando no "check" ao lado da mesma. Recomendo que leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Tente usar `.val()`
Remova este trecho de código

```
$("select#cidade option").each(function() {
    this.selected = (this.text === cidade);
    console.log(this.selected);
});
```

E insira este

```
$("select#cidade").val(cidade);
```