# Como mudar o valor de um select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um script que verifica a diferença entre dois conjuntos de datas, e quero que quando uma destas diferenças for maior que a outra, que o `value` anteriormente escolhido de um certo `select` mude.

Como um trecho de código vale mais que mil palavras:

```
 if (daysc > daysb) {

    $("#var1").show();
    $("#var2").hide();
    $("#var3").val('mudaestevalor');
}
```

Mas não está dando certo. Eu tenho uma outra função depois desta, que abre uma `div` apenas se `$var3` tiver certo valor:

```
if ($('#var3').val() == 'mudaestevalor')
        {
       abre div

        }
```

Mas ela não está mudando com `.val()`. Tentei outras variantes, olhei algumas respostas  [daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5968/atribuir-item-selecionado-em-um-select) e do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery) e nada. Algumas variantes que testei:

```
$("select#var3").trigger("mudaestevalor");
$("select#var3 option").val('mudaestevalor').change();
$("select#var3 option").val('mudaestevalor');
```

Exemplo mínimo no fiddle: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/axwxbyx6/2/</kbd>

Comment: Seus `<option>` têm o atributo `value`? `$("#var3").val('mudaestevalor');` é a forma correta

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML também? se fizeres um jsFiddle a coisa resolve-se em poucos minutos :)

Comment: Tem sim @bfavaretto... Valeu, vou fazer um fiddle...

Comment: sim @Sergio vou fazer agora mesmo! :)

Comment: O select tem que ter um option com o `value="mudaestevalor"`.

Comment: Fiz alguns testes aqui e de fato não funcionou '-' se alguém quiser testar, eu preciso sair: https://jsfiddle.net/fyoxwzso/

Comment: @KaduAmaral juntaste o event handler depois de mudar o select :P assim não ia funcionar ... -> https://jsfiddle.net/fyoxwzso/1/

Comment: Não sei se é o suficiente, mas coloquei apenas uma condição 2 > 1 pra testar (ao invés das datas), e se vcs notarem, ele até coloca o valor já no select, mas não abre a div...) http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/axwxbyx6/2/ @bfavaretto

Comment: haeuhuahueuae nem me liguei @Sergio tava com fome querendo vir embora comer kkkk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens de fazer isso na ordem certa.

1- adicionar o event handler    > `$('#var3').on('change', function () {`
2- mudar o valor do select          > `$("#var3").val('value2')`
3- disparar o evento `change`  > `.change();`

```
$('#var3').on('change', function () {
    if (this.value == 'value2') $("#div1").show();
    else $("#div1").hide();
});

if (2 > 1) {
    $("#var3").val('value2').change();
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/88ssr62g/

Comment: A era isso mesmo... quando passar pra produção vou colocar todos os scripts num `window.load` e depois minificar... mesmo assim precisaria estar na ordem certa? Ah, e valeu mais uma vez! Abraços!

Comment: @gustavox o `window.load` serve se o `change` fôr gerado pelo utilizador. Se fôr programáticamente pode dar erro. Desde que garantires que o `.change()` vem depois do event handler no decorrimento do script, tudo bem.