# Problema CEP JSON com Select de Estados e Cidades

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Boa tarde,

Estou com um problema com meu select de estados e cidades.

Quando eu digito um **CEP** ele preenche os campos automaticamente, já consigo preencher até o **Estado** mesmo ele sendo um select e melhor ainda não necessitando setar as siglas dos **Estados** em "option value", porém a cidade não é selecionada, veja bem: ela é exibida no campo abaixo ou seja o vínculo entre cidade e estado está funcionando, porém ele não seta a cidade que foi recebida do script de CEP, segue abaixo os códigos:

**cep.js**

```
$("#cep_res").blur(function() {

var url = "http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php";
var cep = $(this).val();

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'cep': cep, 'formato': 'json'},
    async: false,
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {

        if (response.resultado === '1') {

            $("#bairro_res").val(response.bairro);
            $("#logradouro_res").val(response.logradouro);

            var uf = response.uf;
            $("select#estado_ress option").each(function() {
                this.selected = (this.text === uf);
            });

            var cidade = response.cidade;
            $("select#cidade_ress option").each(function() {
                this.selected = (this.text === cidade);
            });

            $("#estado_ress").trigger("change");

        }

    }
 });

});
```

**formulário.php**

```
        <label>Estado <span>*</span></label>
        <select class="classic" name="estado_res" id="estado_ress">
            <option value="0">Selecione</option>
            <?php
                $q = "SELECT * FROM estado ORDER BY nome";
                $g = connect($q);
                while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($g[0])){
                    echo '<option value="'.$e['id'].'">'.$e['uf'].'</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#estado_ress').change(function(){
                    var param = $(this).val();

                    $.post("../escola/busca_cidade.php", { est: param }, function(valor){
                            $("#aqui_cidadec").html(valor);

                        }

                    );
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div id="aqui_cidadec">
            <label>Cidade <span>*</span></label>
            <select class="classic" name="cidade_res" id="cidade_ress" style="text-transform:none !important;">
                    <option value="0">Selecione</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

**busca_cidade.php**

```
<?php

require_once('./lib/classes/conexao.php'); 
require_once('./lib/functions/functions.func.php'); 
require_once('./lib/classes/mysql.class.php');
if(!empty($_REQUEST['est'])){

    $q = "SELECT * FROM cidade WHERE estado = '".$_REQUEST['est']."'";
    $g = connect($q);
    echo '<label>Cidade <span>*</span></label>';
    echo '<select class="classic" name="cidade_res" id="cidade_ress">
                <option value="0">Selecione</option>';

    while ( $l = mysql_fetch_assoc($g[0]) ) {
        echo '<option value="'.$l['id'].'">'.$l['nome'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
} else { ; }
?>
```

Ao final do **formulario.php** eu tenho o seguinte script:

```
<script src="<?php echo $url_site; ?>lib/js/cep.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Quem tiver sugestões do que pode ser feito ou algum erro que cometi, pode comentar aí!

Comment: Encontrei alguém com um problema semelhante, porém pra mim a solução atribuída não funcionou: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5968/atribuir-item-selecionado-em-um-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Não é recomendado usar `async: false`. Veja o porquê [**nesta pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48011/8063).

Isso é porque você está querendo pegar a cidade antes de processar o Ajax que troca o Estado e popula o `select` das cidades, assim o código não sabe qual `option` selecionar.

Precisa fazer o laço...

```
$("select#cidade_ress option").each(function() {
    this.selected = (this.text === cidade);
});
```

...após o `select` das cidades ser populado. Faça o seguinte: envie o valor da cidade como parâmetro do `trigger` para o Ajax dos estados e coloque o laço naquele Ajax:

```
var cidade = response.cidade;
$("#estado_ress").trigger("change", cidade);
```

E no Ajax dos Estados (evento `change`), receba o valor `cidade` enviado pelo `trigger` e faça o laço:

```
$('#estado_ress').change(function(e, cidade){
   var param = $(this).val();

   $.post("../escola/busca_cidade.php", { est: param }, function(valor){
      $("#aqui_cidadec").html(valor);

      $("select#cidade_ress option").each(function() {
         this.selected = (this.text === cidade);
      });

   });
});
```

**Resumindo, o Ajax do CEP ficaria assim:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'cep': cep, 'formato': 'json'},
    async: false,
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {

        if (response.resultado === '1') {

            $("#bairro_res").val(response.bairro);
            $("#logradouro_res").val(response.logradouro);

            var uf = response.uf;
            $("select#estado_ress option").each(function() {
                this.selected = (this.text === uf);
            });

            var cidade = response.cidade;

            $("#estado_ress").trigger("change", cidade);

        }

    }
 });

});
```

E o dos Estados assim:

```
$('#estado_ress').change(function(e, cidade){
   var param = $(this).val();

   $.post("../escola/busca_cidade.php", { est: param }, function(valor){
      $("#aqui_cidadec").html(valor);

      $("select#cidade_ress option").each(function() {
         this.selected = (this.text === cidade);
      });

   });
});
```

### Edit

Função para remover os acentos dos nomes das cidades:

```
function remAcentos(p){

   var acc = {
      'â': 'a', 'à': 'a', 'ã': 'a', 'â': 'a', 'á': 'a',
      'é': 'e', 'ê': 'e',
      'í': 'i',
      'ó': 'o', 'õ': 'o', 'ô': 'o',
      'ú': 'u'
   }

   return p.replace(/[áàãâéêíóõôú]/g, function(m){
      return acc[m];
   });

}
```

Para usar a função, inclua a variável `cidade` ao chamá-la:

```
$('#estado_ress').change(function(e, cidade){

      cidade = remAcentos(cidade); // AQUI REMOVE OS ACENTOS

      $("select#cidade_ress option").each(function() {
         this.selected = (this.text.toLowerCase() === cidade);
      });

});
```

Também é interessante adicionar um `toLowerCase()` aqui:

```
this.selected = (this.text.toLowerCase() === cidade);
```

Porque pode ser que alguma cidade pode vir com letra maiúscula acentuada. Com `toLowerCase()` esse problema é contornado.

Comment: Funcionou certinho aqui cara!
Era isso mesmo que tava acontecendo então, não me atentei para os laços!

Só mais uma coisa, a minha base de dados está com as cidades todas sem acentuação então quando digito o CEP de uma cidade que tem acento, o valor não bate porque tá vindo lá da consulta no ajax com acento e no meu banco tá sem acento, ai ele não seleciona! Como eu posso contornar isso?

Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Eu já estava ficando doido com esses selects

Comment: Tranquilo, vou colocar na resposta daqui a pouco o que vc pode fazer pra resolver o problema dos acentos.

Comment: Veja lá, coloquei uma função só pra isso. É bom que vc pode usar ela sempre que quiser remover acentos.

Comment: Não deixe de marcar ✓ na resposta. Abs!

Comment: Show de bola! Funcionou aqui.Tá marcado já!

E muito obrigado novamente amigo!